# Mapbox gl js url parameter

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

We have configured mapbox gl js successfully. We have a working map with locations / stores that are clickable which show the mapbox map popup, giving the user some details e.g., contact information, opening hours etc...

[image]

We are wanting to have parameter within a URL to easily access a specific listing (store/location) for example:

https://example.com/store-locator?store=1, by accessing the "store locator" with the ID 1 in the URL we would like the map to focus in on that location and have the mapbox popup show - matching location e.g., 1. For this case, let's suppose the JSON property "LocationX" is to be given an ID which is 1

I tried with the below code, but was not successful

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const storeID = urlParams.get('branch')
        console.log(storeID);

        $(document).ready(function() {
                if (storeID == "1") {
                  $("#link-0").click();
                };
        })
```

#Link-0 is the id for one of the locations/listings.

```
<div id="listing-0" class="item active"><a href="#/" class="title" id="link-0">Broxburn</a><div>
```

**Mapbox GL JS**

```
/**
       * Add the map to the page
       */
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-1.5466858011960802, 53.478230478528126],
        zoom: 5,
        scrollZoom: true
      });

// Add geolocate control to the map.
map.addControl(
new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
positionOptions: {
enableHighAccuracy: true
},
// When active the map will receive updates to the device's location as it changes.
trackUserLocation: true,
// Draw an arrow next to the location dot to indicate which direction the device is heading.
showUserHeading: true
})
);

      const stores = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': [-3.4524379167753025, 55.942792181678804]
            },
          'properties': {
          'refName': 'Broxburn',
              'phoneFormatted': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'phone': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'phone2': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'address': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'city': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'country': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'postalCode': 'xxx xxx',
              'email': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'service1': 'xxxxxxx',
              'service2': 'xxxxxxx',
              'weekday': 'xxxxxxx - xxxxxxx',
              'weekend': 'xxxxxxx - xxxxxxx',
              'sunday': 'Closed'
            }
          },
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': [-2.9544548591328614, 54.92245269446434]
            },
          'properties': {
          'refName': 'Carlisle',
              'phoneFormatted': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'phone': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'phone2': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'address': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'city': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'country': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'postalCode': 'xxx xxx',
              'email': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'service1': 'xxxxxxx',
              'service2': 'xxxxxxx',
              'weekday': 'xxxxxxx - xxxxxxx',
              'weekend': 'xxxxxxx - xxxxxxx',
              'sunday': 'Closed'
            }
           }   
          }
        ]
      };

      /**
       * Assign a unique id to each store. You'll use this `id`
       * later to associate each point on the map with a listing
       * in the sidebar.
       */
      stores.features.forEach((store, i) => {
        store.properties.id = i;
      });

      /**
       * Wait until the map loads to make changes to the map.
       */
      map.on('load', () => {




        /**
         * This is where your '.addLayer()' used to be, instead
         * add only the source without styling a layer
         */
        map.addSource('places', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': stores
        });

        /**
         * Create a new MapboxGeocoder instance.
         */
        const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
          accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
          mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
          marker: true,
          
        });

          /**
         * Add all the things to the page:
         * - The location listings on the side of the page
         * - The search box (MapboxGeocoder) onto the map
         * - The markers onto the map
         */
        buildLocationList(stores);
        map.addControl(geocoder, 'top-left');
        addMarkers();

        /**
         * Listen for when a geocoder result is returned. When one is returned:
         * - Calculate distances
         * - Sort stores by distance
         * - Rebuild the listings
         * - Adjust the map camera
         * - Open a popup for the closest store
         * - Highlight the listing for the closest store.
         */
        geocoder.on('result', (event) => {
          /* Get the coordinate of the search result */
          const searchResult = event.result.geometry;

          /**
           * Calculate distances:
           * For each store, use turf.disance to calculate the distance
           * in miles between the searchResult and the store. Assign the
           * calculated value to a property called `distance`.
           */
          const options = { units: 'miles' };
          for (const store of stores.features) {
            store.properties.distance = turf.distance(
              searchResult,
              store.geometry,
              options
            );
          }

          /**
           * Sort stores by distance from closest to the `searchResult`
           * to furthest.
           */
          stores.features.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.properties.distance > b.properties.distance) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.properties.distance < b.properties.distance) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0; // a must be equal to b
          });

          /**
           * Rebuild the listings:
           * Remove the existing listings and build the location
           * list again using the newly sorted stores.
           */
          const listings = document.getElementById('listings');
          while (listings.firstChild) {
            listings.removeChild(listings.firstChild);
          }
          buildLocationList(stores);

          /* Open a popup for the closest store. */
          createPopUp(stores.features[0]);

          /** Highlight the listing for the closest store. */
          const activeListing = document.getElementById(
            `listing-${stores.features[0].properties.id}`
          );
          activeListing.classList.add('active');

          /**
           * Adjust the map camera:
           * Get a bbox that contains both the geocoder result and
           * the closest store. Fit the bounds to that bbox.
           */
          const bbox = getBbox(stores, 0, searchResult);
          map.fitBounds(bbox, {
            padding: 100
          });
        });
      });

      /**
       * Using the coordinates (lng, lat) for
       * (1) the search result and
       * (2) the closest store
       * construct a bbox that will contain both points
       */
      function getBbox(sortedStores, storeIdentifier, searchResult) {
        const lats = [
          sortedStores.features[storeIdentifier].geometry.coordinates[1],
          searchResult.coordinates[1]
        ];
        const lons = [
          sortedStores.features[storeIdentifier].geometry.coordinates[0],
          searchResult.coordinates[0]
        ];
        const sortedLons = lons.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a > b) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.distance < b.distance) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        const sortedLats = lats.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a > b) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.distance < b.distance) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        return [
          [sortedLons[0], sortedLats[0]],
          [sortedLons[1], sortedLats[1]]
        ];
      }

      /**
       * Add a marker to the map for every store listing.
       **/
      function addMarkers() {
        /* For each feature in the GeoJSON object above: */
        for (const marker of stores.features) {
          /* Create a div element for the marker. */
          const el = document.createElement('div');
          /* Assign a unique `id` to the marker. */
          el.id = `marker-${marker.properties.id}`;
          /* Assign the `marker` class to each marker for styling. */
          el.className = 'marker';

          /**
           * Create a marker using the div element
           * defined above and add it to the map.
           **/
          new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [0, -23] })
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .addTo(map);

          /**
           * Listen to the element and when it is clicked, do three things:
           * 1. Fly to the point
           * 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
           * 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
           **/
          el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            flyToStore(marker);
            createPopUp(marker);
            const activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (activeItem[0]) {
              activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
            }
            const listing = document.getElementById(
              `listing-${marker.properties.id}`
            );
            listing.classList.add('active');
          });
        }
      }

      /**
       * Add a listing for each store to the sidebar.
       **/
      function buildLocationList(stores) {
        for (const store of stores.features) {
          /* Add a new listing section to the sidebar. */
          const listings = document.getElementById('listings');
          const listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
          /* Assign a unique `id` to the listing. */
          listing.id = `listing-${store.properties.id}`;
          /* Assign the `item` class to each listing for styling. */
          listing.className = 'item';

          /* Add the link to the individual listing created above. */
          const link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
          link.href = '#/';
          link.className = 'title';
          link.id = `link-${store.properties.id}`;
          link.innerHTML = `${store.properties.refName}`;

           /* Add details to the individual listing. */
          const details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
          details.innerHTML = details.innerHTML = `${store.properties.address}, ${store.properties.city}`;
          if (store.properties.phone) {
            details.innerHTML += ` &middot; ${store.properties.phoneFormatted}`;
          }

          if (store.properties.service1) {
            
            details.innerHTML += `<br><i class="fa-solid fa-truck-front"></i>`;

      if (store.properties.service2) { details.innerHTML +=`<i data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom" class="fa-solid fa-spray-can" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i>`;

if (store.properties.service3) { details.innerHTML +=`<i class="fa-solid fa-helmet-safety" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i>`;

     }
       }
          }

          /**
           * Listen to the element and when it is clicked, do four things:
           * 1. Update the `currentFeature` to the store associated with the clicked link
           * 2. Fly to the point
           * 3. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
           * 4. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
           **/
          link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            for (const feature of stores.features) {
              if (this.id === `link-${feature.properties.id}`) {
                flyToStore(feature);
                createPopUp(feature);
              }
            }
            const activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
            if (activeItem[0]) {
              activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
            }
            this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
          });
        }
      }

      /**
       * Use Mapbox GL JS's `flyTo` to move the camera smoothly
       * a given center point.
       **/
      function flyToStore(currentFeature) {
        map.flyTo({
          center: currentFeature.geometry.coordinates,
          zoom: 15
        });
      }

      /**
       * Create a Mapbox GL JS `Popup`.
       **/
      function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
        const popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
        if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();

        const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: false })
          .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
          .setHTML(
            `<h3>Company Name - ${currentFeature.properties.refName}</h3>
            
            <h4>${currentFeature.properties.address}, ${currentFeature.properties.city}, ${currentFeature.properties.postalCode}</h4>
            
            <h4><i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>Mon-Fri:<span style="margin-right:19px"></span> ${currentFeature.properties.weekday}<br><i style="margin-right:17px" class=""></i>Saturday: <span style="margin-right:10px"></span> ${currentFeature.properties.weekend}<br><i style="margin-right:17px" class=""></i>Sunday: <span style="margin-right:20px"></span> ${currentFeature.properties.sunday}</h4>
            
            <h4><i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>${currentFeature.properties.phone} <br></h4>
            
            <div style="padding:0;" id="alt-phone2" class="alt-phone2"> <h4 style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"><i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>${currentFeature.properties.phone2}</h4></div>
            
            <div style="padding:0;" id="alt-phone2" class="alt-phone3"> <h4 style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"><i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>${currentFeature.properties.phone3}</h4></div>

            <h4 style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"><i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>${currentFeature.properties.email}</h4>`
            
            
          
          )
          
          .addTo(map);
          
           if (currentFeature.properties.phone2 === undefined) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("alt-phone2")[0].style.display = "none";
                }

           if (currentFeature.properties.phone3 === undefined) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("alt-phone3")[0].style.display = "none";
                }
          
         
          
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code looks good, but there is likely a race condition between the `$(document).ready(...)` and the `map.on('load', ...)` events. The first one fires before the second one. That means, your JavaScript that "clicks" on a link tries to click on a link that doesn't yet exist in the DOM. If this is the case, the solution is to move the "clicking" code after the code that creates the links.

i.e. create this function:

```
function clickSelectedStore() {
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const storeID = urlParams.get('branch')
  console.log(storeID);
  
  if (storeID) {
    $('#link-' + storeID).click();
  }
}
```

and call it at the end of the `map.on('load', ...)` event (after the `buildLocationList(...)` function has already been called.

If that doesn't help, you should create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can see your code in action.

Comment: your suggestion works perfect, kind regards :)